# why php is not sending any message to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql

so i'm sending a value to php code to update an entry in my sql database, everything is running fine, entry is updating successfully but php not returning any success or failure message to jquery. i've tried both post and ajax method but every time its same. data updated without alerting any message. why should i do ??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#updateabout").click(function(){
var value = $("#value").val();

            $.post("<?= base_url('user_profile/updatebio'); ?>", {val:value}, function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

here's my php code for update:

```
 if($this->session->userdata('LoginId')){

                $uid = $this->session->userdata('LoginId');
                $val = $_POST['val'];
  $que = "update dzone_usersignup_details set about_me='$val' where uid='$uid'";
                $run = mysqli_query($conn, $ru)
                if($run){
                    echo "hello";
                }
            }
```

Comment: The Ajax request is expecting a Json response, so use echo json_encode(array("success"=>true, "text" => "hello"));

Comment: You can also change the header to..  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @CarlSmith you can `echo 'hello';` from php and the value would be returned. In this case `if ($run)` doesn't run. put an `else` statement and `echo 'goodbye';`.

Comment: @CarlSmith Where do you see the AJAX code expecting JSON?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Check the Network tab to see what response the AJAX request is returning.

Comment: hey guess thx for ur comments and time..the only problem was. i was leaving the form action blank . thats why it was redirecting to same page and not alerting anything.

Answer (score -1):

Check your console, you must missing something.

Or try return instead of echo in php

Comment: yup u were right i was missing something. now problem has been resolved thx bro for ur comment